# Scala anonymous function (creating a new function based on one passed)

Tags: scala

I've a function where I'm trying to modify a function I've been passed (p) in an anonymous function, then use it as a parameter to f2.

Here's the code;

```
def f1(i: Int, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
  !f2(s,(a :Int=>Boolean) = !p(a) )
}

def f2(i: Int, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean
```

But this won't compile due to missing markers, and I'm a bit stumped.
James

Comment: are you sure about the line 2 in f1 def?

Comment: Personally I find your question hard to understand, who is `s`? And what are you trying to do passing in `!p` as function?  You can negate the result of `f2` (or not probably in your case since double negation is an affirmation), but as I said, looks very confusing to me.

Comment: do you mean: `!f2(i, a => !p(a))` ?

Comment: Sorry, incomplete edit by myself, s on the f2 line should be i. I'm trying to reuse a function f2, but need to supply a negation of the function p and then negate the output. I thought I could create an anonymous function to return the negation of p and use this as a parameter to f2. The f2 line is to show the function declaratino at this point.

Comment: If I try that Gzou, I get "not found: value a" error, but a is supplied in f2.

Comment: Coursera course is running again, I see! (and honor code not being, er, honored?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try and do this:

```
def f1(i: Int, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
  !f2(i,(a :Int=>Boolean) = !p )
}

def f2(i: Int, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean
```

Answer (score -1):

Gzou was right, the problem I had was not including a space between the => and !. Thanks for that, very helpful,

Comment: Point 1.) I did upvote Gzou's comment above. 2.) I can't accept a comment as an answer and as the question had been answered, I put a note here to direct the reading to the comment. I was going to put this as as accepted answer, but the system makes you wait for two days.